# jackson read node field with $ symbol

Tags: scala, jackson, jackson-databind

response from API looks like

```
  "node1": [
       {
           "＄field": "https://somethingh.com",
           "type": "object",
           "meta:Type": "object"
       },
       {
           "＄field": "https://somethingelse.com",
           "type": "object",
           "meta:Type": "object"
       }
   ],
```

When retrieving the node by key , some times it is retrieving , some time objNode.get("$field") returns null. so getting null pointer exception.

What are the ways i can avoid it . I dont want to use get(0) ( the index of the element) . because latter thee position may change..

```
    val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
    val node = mapper.readTree(res)
    val nodelist = node.get("node1")

    if (nodelist != null) {
     
      for (objNode <- nodelist) {
        println(s"objNode => $objNode  and  value => ${objNode.get("$field")} ")
        val fieldColumn = objNode.get("$field").textValue()
}
```

Comment: It is probably because you are using two different dollar signs in `JSON` payload and `Scala` code. Take a look on list of [dollar signs](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/search?q=dollar#characters). Try to copy dollar sign from a payload and put to code file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the $ which was a special character . The code worked as is.